# Mongoose give aliases to fields before sending the data to client side

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, alias

i have this function that returns `employees` as an array of objects and send it to client side

```
const getEmployees = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const employees = await Employee.find({}, { __v: 0 });
    res.status(200).json(employees);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(400).json(err);
  }
};
```

it looks like something like this :

```
[
{accountNumber: 1 , employeeName: john}
{accountNumber: 2 , employeeName: oscar}
{accountNumber: 3 , employeeName: franc}

]
```

**TableContainer.js**

```
function TableContainer({ table }) {

  const [data, setData] = useState([{}]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {

        const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/get-employees");
        const data = await response.json();
        setData(data);
      
    };
    getData();
  }, []);

   return (
        <table className="table">

          <thead>
            <tr>
              {filteredData.length > 0 &&
                Object.keys(filteredData[0]).map((key) => (
                  <th key={key}> {key} </th>
                ))}
            </tr>
          </thead>

          <tbody>
            {filteredData.length > 0 &&
              filteredData.map((item, i) => (
                <tr key={i}>
                  {Object.values(item).map((val, i) => (
                    <td key={i}>{val}</td>
                  ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
}
```

now the table headers will be **accountNumber** and **employeeName**, but this is not appropriate for user to read, i want them to rather be `Account Number` and `Employee Name`, is there a way to change fields names on the server side before sending the data rather than missing up with the array in the react component or change the fields names in the collection ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just use the following projection:

```
const employees = await Employee.find({}, { 'Account number': '$accountNumber', 'Employee Name': '$employeeName'});
```

Comment: that gives an error ```Cannot do exclusion on field __v in inclusion projection```, if i removed ```__v : 0``` ( for experiment ), it will indeed returns ```Account Number```, but that's the only thing it returns, ```Employee Name``` will be excluded from the returned array

Comment: i think that's because mongoose query doesn't allow inclusion and exclusion together in projection

Comment: Yeah, my bad. If `__v` is not included in this projection, it will be ignored. Therefore it should be still valid. Can you check if the attribute in the collection is really named 'employeeName'?

Comment: my bad, its called ```nameEN```, now it worked, i need to include needed fields in the projection in order to return all of them